# Need help in Date formula

Tags: apex, formula, validation, validation-rule

I have a date field (Last_Order_Date__c), in which I am defaulting the value of date to 6 months ahead from today's date.

**Default Value for Above Date Field with formula**

```
DATE( 
YEAR(TODAY()) + IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 6, 1, 0), 
MOD(MONTH(TODAY()) + 6, 12), 
DAY(TODAY()) 
)
```

Right now it is defaulting the value correctly.
Suppose today is 10/29/2016 .It is defaultly setting to this value 4/29/2017.
My first question: Is this formula correct for defaulting the date value to the date which is 6months ahead.
Will it also consider Months having 31st automatically?
FYI I am getting below error if today's date is 10/31/2016 and I am using the above formula for default date.

[image]

Comment: Check out this link for useful date formulas:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link @NickCook. I am little confused in Date formula. If you could resolve this issue it could be greatfully for me.

Comment: Your question is really unclear.  What exactly is the problem?  Are you unsure of your default value, or your validation rule? You also need to consider what should happen it the future month doesn't have that many days.  What should happen?  what's Dec 31 + 6 months?  June 30, or July 1?

Comment: Why are you defaulting 'Last_Order_Date__c' to be 6 month ahead from **today**? It will always show 6 month ahead date event if you open the record after a month. You need to reference a field, i.e. 'Created Date', in your formula field so that way your calculated date will be fixed to a particular value 6 months in future.

Comment: @Mahmood 'Last_Order_Date__c' is a Date field.When I open the record I am defaulting to 6month ahead date so that user don"t  need to select.How will be the formula if we uses CreatedDate inspite of Today().Any Idea?

Comment: Hi @NickCook. If it is Dec 31st then future date need to be July1st.

Comment: Nick Cook defined your issue - the `DATE` function takes in three arguments - year, month, day. The value of `day` has to be valid for the supplied `month` and `year`. Thus `DATE(2017,4,31)` is out of range

Comment: Hi @cropredy. I understood the point .What could be the solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Sample Date Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm), specifically the **Adding Days, Months, and Years to a Date** section:

```
DATE(
  YEAR( date ) + FLOOR( ( MONTH ( date ) + 6 - 1 ) / 12 ),
  MOD( MONTH ( date ) + 6 - 1 + 
    IF( DAY ( date ) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( date ) + 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1, 
      2, 28,
      4, 30,
      6, 30,
      9, 30, 
      11, 30,
      31 ), 1, 0 ), 12 ) + 1,
    IF( DAY( date ) > CASE( MOD( MONTH( date ) + 6 - 1, 12 ) + 1,
      2, 28, 
      4, 30, 
      6, 30, 
      9, 30, 
      11, 30, 
      31 ), 
    1, DAY( date )
  )
)
```

Where *date* should be replaced with the date you want.  i.e. today()

> This formula does the following:
>
> - Returns March 1 if the future month is a February and the day is greater than 28. This portion of the formula performs the same for both leap and non-leap years.
> - Returns the first day of the next month if the future month is April, June, September, or November and the day is greater than 30.
> - Otherwise, it returns the correct date in the future month.

Comment: @Dinesh; you might want to alter the above to coerce 10/31/16 -> 4/30/17 etc for 31 -> 30 day mos. This is a business use case decision